# Send gridview data from client side to server side at once

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview, web

In an ASP.NET 2.0 web application, there is a gridview containing checkbox in first column.
When checkbox is checked either Header Checkbox or Row Checkbox, OnCheckChange event triggers on server side. In this event, the specfic row data or all rows data (in case of header checkbox) is added to a data table in session for further processing. Along side this, it call a few javascript function as well to check/uncheck the checkboxes, highlight the row on client side.

In case, when user wanted to check multiple checkbox but not via header checkbox.  It's behavior gets wrong. If user quickly check the checkbox, few checkboxes are checked and few remain unchecked.
What I guess is that since on each OnCheckChange event there is a request to server side and then some js methods so it takes time, but befor request completeed, user checked the next checkbox and it is not actually checked.

Is there any way, I can allow user to check how many checkboxes he/she wants to check and then send them to server for storing in data table ?

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using AJAX when OnCheckChange fires on server?

Comment: Yes. Ajax is used is used in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add loader for this kind of functionality. I hope you should be using update panel. You can add update progress control for the time request is processing on server side. It will hint the user to wait. You can also use ajax request by jquery to do similar kind of work.

Comment: I'm already using update progress control which is associated with that update panel. What I'm doing is disabling gridview and showing a image (loading symbol) on it in InitializeRequest() function and reverting back this to normal state in EndRequest() function. And these functions are:                                              var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

Comment: but still issue exists

Comment: You should try Jquery ajax requests instead of update panel because its performance is slower than ajax calls via jquery. In this way you can disable other checkboxes on client side when the request is in progress. Other thing you can have is that have a div element with the height and width of page's max height and width and make it visible with the loader. I believe it will solve the problem.